# Get value to display as checkbox - not T or F

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

In design mode in management studio I have added a row to the table 'Checked', it has a 'bit' as a data type, and is stored as either true or false.

I can get this to display fine on screen(Using a repeater), however instead of displaying true or false, I want to use a check box, which is ticked or unticked depending on T or F.

aspx:

```
<th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Checked") %></th>
```

Behind:

```
DBData db = new DBDatat();
        List<Select_Utility> SelectedUtility = 
            (from SU in db.Select_Utilities
             where SU.Work_Id == 3
             select SU).ToList();

        rptSelectedUtilities.DataSource = SelectedUtility;
        rptSelectedUtilities.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  are doing correct. instead of plain text, replace with checkbox

```
<th style="width:200px;">
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkMyCheck" runat="server" 
           Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Checked")) %>'/>
</th>
```